# Keycloak : How to implement custom authenticator to intercept SAML response?

Tags: saml, keycloak, adfs

We have integrated ADFS with Keycloak and Keycloak with Angular web app. we are getting below status tag from ADFS:

```
<samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied"/></samlp:StatusCode>
    </samlp:Status>
```

I want to display Error message/page after getting RequestDenied Response

Please, suggest any possible way to implement Keycloak custom Authenticator to intercept SAML response.

Comment: imho the samlEndpoint always throws an error/create an error page if the SAML Response status is not "Success"
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/broker/saml/SAMLEndpoint.java#L360
I think you can`t intercept that with an Authenticator but maybe configure/render a custom error page (if the error status contains the specific statusMessage)

Comment: Thanks @Evil_skunk. Is there any Keycloak configuration to check SAML status and display error page?